# How to Format/Overwrite Django Form Error Message?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    no = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': u'must be xxx')
```

template.html

```
{{form.no.error}}
```

`{{form.no.error}}` is `<ul class="errorlist"><li>must be xxx</li></ul>`
I want to format `{{form.no.error}}` to plain text message without any html tags

Comment: This is covered in the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template

Answer (score 24):

You could either just remove the tags:

```
{{ form.no.errors|striptags }}
```

Or just access the raw error:

```
{{ form.no.errors.as_text }}
```

Comment: I wanna format the error message with some html tags for template show,can I format the message in forms.py, not in template with js?

Comment: It's going to be somewhat complicated. The generation of `<html>` is done in the `ErrorDict` class. You would have to somehow modify that. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/util.py#L26 or the form class directly. Another option would be to create a template filter that would insert custom html.

Comment: A bit late as a response, so just for reference: you can quite easily write a custom error list class and pass that to any form inside Python: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format